# Linux Shell Script help Need to parse out data from log file between two words

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Hi I'm looking to parse a log file and get the following data out and assign to variable and do an if statement if the condition is met:

Here is the input of the log file:

```
host123.src_dist.serviceGenerator.srcPrdServicePool.1234_REC.dataStreams.activeStale:0
host123.src_dist.serviceGenerator.srcPrdServicePool.YYY_CONTROL.dataStreams.activeStale: 5
host123.src_dist.serviceGenerator.srcPrdServicePool.TPSG.dataStreams.activeStale: 0
host123.src_dist.serviceGenerator.srcPrdServicePool.LDN_ABC.dataStreams.activeStale: 10
host123.src_dist.serviceGenerator.srcPrdServicePool.SSS_BOR.dataStreams.activeStale: 0
```

Logic is

```
if activeStale is > 0   
then 
    echo YYY_CONTROL  >> filenamex
    echo LDN_ABC      >> filenamexz       
endif
```

The resulting file is  `cat filenamex`

```
YYY_CONTROL
LDN_ABC
```

I can do the if part but not sure how to yank out the service names YYY_CONTROL from the line? srcPrdServicePool.YYY_CONTROL.dataStreams

So the simple question is, how can I yank out the service names from the lines that meet my condition?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you want to print them to the same file (note that in your pseudocode this is not the case). I would use awk for this:

```
awk -F':' '$2 > 0 { split($1, a, "."); print a[5]}' file
```

This tests the value after the colon is greater than `0` and if so, prints the part you are interested in.

```
bash-4.2$ awk -F':' '$2 > 0 { split($1, a, "."); print a[5]}' file
YYY_CONTROL        
LDN_ABC
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way with `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F: '$2>0 && match($0,/Pool[.]([^.]+)[.]dataStreams/,ary) && $0=ary[1]' file
```

```
$ awk -F: '$2>0 && match($0,/Pool[.]([^.]+)[.]dataStreams/,ary) && $0=ary[1]' file
YYY_CONTROL
LDN_ABC
```

Comment: +1, I was tempted to use regular expressions myself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` and `cut` (assuming your log file is always formatted the same way):

```
 awk -F: '$NF>0' my_file.log | cut -d. -f5 > filenamex
```

`awk` looks at everything after the last colon, if it is greater than 0 then that line is printed. `cut` splits the line into fields by using `.` as a delimiter, then looks at the 5th field, which is the value you want.

Comment: josh this will not work for what I have in mind thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with implicit splitting by setting `FS`, for example:

```
awk '$2>0 { FS="."; $0=$0; print $5; FS=":" }' FS=: file
```

Output:

```
YYY_CONTROL
LDN_ABC
```